# C:\Users now reads C:\Google Drive

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-explorer, icons

During a change of the folder location for Google Drive, Explorer crashed and when the dust cleared the "C:\Users" directory was now renamed to "C:\Google Drive". To add insult to injury, the folder icon is the Windows SkyDrive/OneDrive icon. This is only evident when using File Explorer however, because the underlying folder name is still "C:\users"

I would like to change this back to a regular folder icon and change the name back to "C:\Users" but the option to change the name is grayed out and changing the folder icon does not work.

Comment: What if you uninstall google drive or onedrive?

Comment: Have you tried System Restore to a date before the crash?

Comment: The issue appears to be that renaming this folder would fail under normal procedures whether I was using Google Drive or OneDrive. It's a problem in renaming on any Windows machine, not just those running Google Drive or OneDrive.

Comment: I have not tried a System State restore. I'm hoping that I can find a registry setting that effects this naming ability without going that route.

Answer (score 3):

I would place my money on there being a file with Hidden+System attributes named `C:\users\desktop.ini`.

This is a special INI file that permits you to set an icon file and rename a folder.

Try this, Open up Powershell as Administrator and run the command `gci -Hidden C:\users`.  I bet you will see a file named `desktop.ini` in the returned list.  Remove it with the command `rm -force c:\users\desktop.ini`.

You might need to restart for this change to take effect since this per-folder information is cached by the file browser.

Comment: The hidden desktop.ini file deletion was the ticket. That and a reboot.  Thank you very much!